# what is this component and the brand name ? P527 DGM

Tags: components

[image]

Im studying this board's circuit. But cannot find what's this P527 DGM component is. Could anyone tell me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a TVS diode from the Chinese company [BrightKing](http://www.brightking.com).  It appears to be a clone of the Littlefuse [SMDJ64CA](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smdj_datasheet.pdf.pdf).  The picture below shows a clip from the SMDJ page on the BrightKing website.  Note the matching logo on the part.

[image: BrightKing]

[Here](http://www.brightking.com/gdbzjy201608037528/uploadfiles/file/TVS/2016122916404340432274.pdf) is a link to the BrightKing SMDJ datasheet.

Below are clips from the datasheets showing the specs for the parts. LittleFuse is in green followed by BrightKing in red.  Note the package marking code DGM for the bidirectional part.  For small parts, manufacturers often use marking codes, since the full part number does not fit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To give a brief summary of the purpose, usually these devices are intended to prevent high voltages from damaging parallel components. If the TVS is rated for 64V standoff then some amount above this voltage it begins to conduct in an attempt to clamp the voltage spike to a survivable level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the manufacturer logo, but the SMD marking (DGM) and the package (DO-214AB?) point to it being some kind of transient voltage suppression (TVS) diode.

Probably something like this:
http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smdj_datasheet.pdf.pdf

You can use a multimeter to check if it's unidirectional or bidirectional.

Comment: Considering there is no marking on the package or the board, odds are it is bidirectional.